# Miniature relay: long-term continuously on?

Tags: relay

I'm in the process of designing/building a pre-amp, and I want to use relays for input switching. I'm considering Omron G6K miniature relays for this, but the data sheet has the following to say about "Long-term Continuously ON Contacts":

> Using the Relay in a circuit where the Relay will be ON
> continuously for long periods (without switching) can lead to
> unstable contacts because the heat generated by the coil itself
> will affect the insulation, causing a film to develop on the
> contact surfaces.

Ok, clear, but ... what is a long period? Is this minutes, hours, days? The alternative is to use latching relays but these are a bit more difficult to find and more expensive.

Also, can this problem be mitigated by driving the coil in a well-controlled manner, i.e., applying a current pulse to close the relay and then reducing the current to the holding current to keep the relay closed? This should reduce heat generation I believe, and according to the quote above prolong contact life?

Lastly, as I'm a total beginner, I'm totally open for other product/relay suggestions that would be easy to source and similarly or better suited for the task!

Comment: Well, it all depends on the current flowing through the contacts. Relays are usually designed to handle "large" currents, e.g. 1A to 10A is not uncommon. But for your preamp applications. the voltage is or order millivolts and currents passing through the very low resistance contacts is "minimal", perhaps just of order much less than milliamperes. In other words, "no" heat would be generated.

Comment: Why can't you use multiplexers for switching the inputs like mostly everyone else?

Comment: You need to include a link to the manufacturer's datasheet for the specific relay you have in mind.

Comment: How about using a latching (bistable) relay?  Two coils, one to turn on, one to turn off, does not require current on either coil to maintain the setting.

Comment: The quote from the datasheet seems to imply that the coil heat is the issue, not the contacts. That makes sense, as the resistance across the contacts is negligible, so that is not going to generate heat.
I might end up using a latching/bistable relay indeed, that might be a lot simpler, but those are a bit more difficult to find (less choice, higher prices)